# Webpack ERROR in Path must be a string. Received undefined

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm update my node.js to version 7. And after run webpack in project I received error message: `ERROR in Path must be a string. Received undefined`

My package.json :

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.3.1",
    "react-native": "^0.33.0",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "react-web": "0.4.5",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "remote-redux-devtools": "^0.4.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.7",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^1.9.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.16.0",
    "haste-resolver-webpack-plugin": "^0.2.2",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2",
    "webpack-html-plugin": "^0.1.1"
  }
```

Anybody has a suggestion? How resolve this problem?

Comment: same problem here

Comment: Same problem here as well... any updates?

Answer (score 7):

When I am learning [Writing your AngularJS with Redux](http://jslancer.com/blog/2016/08/02/writing-your-angularjs-with-redux/)

I got the the error "ERROR in The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
webpack: Failed to compile.[image]"

At last I figured out the issue by add filename (**filename: 'index.html',**) to webpack.config.js accoring to CrzMarvin solution.
[image]

ThX CrzMarvin

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem before,then I think it's something wrong with the plugin. then, I add filename to this plugin.It worked.

// webpack.config.js

```
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        title: 'use plugin',
        filename: 'index.html'
    })
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should install `html-webpack-plugin` dependency instead of `webpack-html-plugin`. I had the same issues before

Answer (score 0):

The following solution is fine and Working for node v14.2.0

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  title: 'use plugin',
  filename: 'index.html',
  template: path.join(client.srcPath, client.entryHtml)
})
```

Comment: Please format your code properly, [click here to learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.